# I can't save my file through model after base64 encode at django-rest

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have fields named image1 and image2 in my model. I'm getting the base64 content of the files when creating (I'll send this to the remote api for another action). When I do base64 conversion, I cannot record in my model. It gives an error like;

> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

models.py

```
class HelpDeskDemandModel(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to="municy_helpdesk_images/%Y/%m/%d/", null=True, blank=True)
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to="municy_helpdesk_images/%Y/%m/%d/", null=True, blank=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class HelpDeskDemandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = HelpDeskDemandModel
        fields = [
            'code', 'image1', 'image2'
        ]


    def create(self, validated_data):
        base64_files = []
        for i in range(1, 3):
            img = validated_data.get(f"image{i}", None)

            if img:
                with img.open('rb') as f:
                    base64_content = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode()
                base64_files.append(base64_content)


        # the error occurs on this line
        instance = HelpDeskDemandModel.objects.create(**validated_data)

        return instance
```

Comment: Your serializer deals with `image1` & `image2` as an image field, not a `base64` or `str`

Comment: I don't already use base64 on this model?

Comment: In the input? NO, can you share what the request body looks like?

Comment: @MohamedHamza I  use DRF?

Answer (score 0):

this is how i solved it.
I created a new object with ContentFile and passed this object to the model

```
validated_data.update({f"image{i}": ContentFile(file_content_byte, img.name)})
```

---

serializers.py

```
class HelpDeskDemandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = HelpDeskDemandModel
        fields = [
            'code', 'image1', 'image2'
        ]


    def create(self, validated_data):
        base64_files = []
        for i in range(1, 3):
            img = validated_data.get(f"image{i}", None)

            if img:
                with img.open('rb') as f:
                file_content_byte=f.read()
                base64_content = base64.b64encode(file_content_byte).decode()
                validated_data.update({f"image{i}": ContentFile(file_content_byte, img.name)})
                base64_files.append(base64_content)


        # the error occurs on this line
        instance = HelpDeskDemandModel.objects.create(**validated_data)

        return instance
```